# flutter: the application crashes when I want to redirect

Tags: android, flutter, crash, navigator

I have been working on a mobile application for a few years and strangely today my application crashes when making a redirect.
For example just when executing the following code: `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/home");`

Here is my SDK version: Dart SDK version 2.14.2

Comment: Can you include your materialApp route?

Comment: I don't understand your quetion

Comment: If you are using  `routes` on  MaterialApp include that part. check [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#2-define-the-routes)

Comment: Please 1. share your log with error. 2. Get your router setting from main.dart (usually).

Comment: Here is my `routes` `GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        
      },
      onPanDown: (_) {
        
      },
      onScaleStart: (_) {
      },
      child: OverlaySupport(
        child: MaterialApp(
          navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
          key: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
          initialRoute: "/",
          routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
            '/login': (context) => LoginPage(),
            '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
          },
          
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );`

Comment: Your application crush without any errors?

Comment: @igdmitrov in my log I have following message : `I/flutter (21930): Size(82.0, 48.0)
I/flutter (21930): Size(82.0, 16.0)
I/flutter (21930): Size(82.0, 24.0)`

Comment: I don't have any error

Comment: I think we need more information, but try test your application on another machine or device.

Comment: Ok I will try to test it with another device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246869/discussion-between-abdoul-razak-adamou-komche-and-igdmitrov).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, my application is blocked by a recursive method. After removing it everything was back to normal.
Thanks [igdmitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16213380/igdmitrov) and [Yeasin Sheikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10157127/yeasin-sheikh) for your supports